# Add row to table/named range with specific values?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm simply trying to add a new row to a table and specify certain values.  Right now, I am adding the row using the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableName").ListRows.Add
```

This works, but now how would I make the first column have the value `foo`?

`ListRows.Add()` only supports one parameter, an index at which it will add the row.  Is there another function I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Your_Table As ListObject
Dim New_Row As ListRow

Set Your_Table =ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableName")
Set New_Row = Your_Table.ListRows.Add

New_Row.Range(1) = foo
```